# Rails broken query after update. Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError. Construct an Arel node instead

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, arel

Ruby on Rails app with PostgreSQL database
There was class with search query constructed with Arel 5.x:

```
class Sample

  def url
    audio_url.gsub(self.class.to_s.underscore, 'user_profile_audio_sample') if audio_url
  end

  class << self

    def search(query={}, app_id='pv', page=1, per_page=20)
      arel = tables.project(
        profile_table[:id].as('profile_id'),
        audio_table[:id].as('id'),
        audio_table[:age].as('age'),
        audio_table[:audio].as('audio'),
        web_site_language_table[:name].as('language_name'),
        audio_categories_table[:name].as('category_name'),
        audio_categories_table[:identifier].as('category_identifier'),
        profile_table[:full_name].as('full_name'),
        profile_table[:nickname].as('nickname'),
        profile_table[:gender].as('gender')
        ).
          where(profile_query).
          where(genders_query(query)).
          where(ages_query(query)).
          where(categories_query(query)).
          where(languages_query(query)).
          where(website_query(app_id)).
          where(audios_query).
          where(audios_published).
          order(profile_table[:id].desc)

      sql = arel.to_sql.gsub(/SELECT/, '\\0 DISTINCT ON (1)')

      paginate_by_sql(sql, page: page, per_page: per_page)
    end

    protected

    def profile_query
      profile_table[:nickname].not_eq(nil)
    end

    def audios_query
      audio_table[:id].not_eq(nil)
    end

    def audios_published
      audio_table[:published].eq(true)
    end

    def languages_query(query={})
      if valid_query_param? query[:languages]
        audio_web_site_language_table[:web_site_language_id].in(query[:languages].select &:present?)
      else
        true
      end
    end

    def website_query(app_id)
      web_sites_table[:app_id].eq(app_id)
    end

    def categories_query(query)
      if valid_query_param? query[:categories]
        audio_table[:audio_category_id].in(query[:categories].select &:present?)
      else
        true
      end
    end

    def ages_query(query)
      if valid_query_param? query[:ages]
        audio_table[:age].in(query[:ages].select &:present?)
      else
        true
      end
    end

    def genders_query(query)
      if valid_query_param? query[:genders]
        profile_table[:gender].in(query[:genders].select &:present?)
      else
        true
      end
    end

    def valid_query_param?(name)
      name.present? && !name.select(&:present?).empty?
    end

    def tables
      profile_table \
      .join(audio_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) \
      .on(profile_table[:id].eq(audio_table[:user_profile_id])) \
      .join(audio_categories_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) \
      .on(audio_table[:audio_category_id].eq(audio_categories_table[:id])) \
      .join(audio_web_site_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) \
      .on(audio_table[:id].eq(audio_web_site_table[:audio_id])) \
      .join(audio_web_site_language_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) \
      .on(audio_web_site_table[:id].eq(audio_web_site_language_table[:audio_web_site_id]))  \
      .join(web_site_language_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) \
      .on(audio_web_site_language_table[:web_site_language_id].eq(web_site_language_table[:id])) \
      .join(web_sites_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) \
      .on(web_site_language_table[:web_site_id].eq(web_sites_table[:id]))
    end

    def profile_table
      Arel::Table.new(:user_profiles)
    end

    def audio_table
      Arel::Table.new(:user_profile_audio_samples)
    end

    def audio_web_site_table
      Arel::Table.new(:user_profile_audio_sample_web_sites)
    end

    def audio_web_site_language_table
      Arel::Table.new(:user_profile_audio_sample_web_site_languages)
    end

    def web_site_language_table
      Arel::Table.new(:web_site_languages)
    end

    def audio_categories_table
      Arel::Table.new(:audio_categories)
    end

    def web_sites_table
      Arel::Table.new(:web_sites)
    end

  end

end
```

The resulting SQL was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) 
"user_profiles"."id" AS profile_id, 
"user_profile_audio_samples"."id" AS id, 
"user_profile_audio_samples"."age" AS age,
"user_profile_audio_samples"."audio" AS audio,
"web_site_languages"."name" AS language_name, 
"audio_categories"."name" AS category_name, 
"audio_categories"."identifier" AS category_identifier, 
"user_profiles"."full_name" AS full_name, 
"user_profiles"."nickname" AS nickname, 
"user_profiles"."gender" AS gender 
FROM "user_profiles" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_profile_audio_samples" ON "user_profiles"."id" = "user_profile_audio_samples"."user_profile_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "audio_categories" ON "user_profile_audio_samples"."audio_category_id" = "audio_categories"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_profile_audio_sample_web_sites" ON "user_profile_audio_samples"."id" = "user_profile_audio_sample_web_sites"."audio_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_profile_audio_sample_web_site_languages" ON "user_profile_audio_sample_web_sites"."id" = "user_profile_audio_sample_web_site_languages"."audio_web_site_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "web_site_languages" ON "user_profile_audio_sample_web_site_languages"."web_site_language_id" = "web_site_languages"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "web_sites" ON "web_site_languages"."web_site_id" = "web_sites"."id" 
WHERE "user_profiles"."nickname" IS NOT NULL AND 't' AND 't' AND 't' AND 't' AND "web_sites"."app_id" = 'pv' AND "user_profile_audio_samples"."id" IS NOT NULL AND "user_profile_audio_samples"."published" = 't'  
ORDER BY "user_profiles"."id" DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

After upgrading to the Rails 6.1 I started to receive an error:
Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError: Unsupported argument type: TrueClass. Construct an Arel node instead.
I believe it connected to the audios_published method. I made an attempt to use Arel::Node::Binary and Arel::Node::Quoted but I don't have enough understanding which Arel classes I need to use. Also I think other methods needs similar change, not only audios_published.
What can be the pattern to return the query to the same state as before upgrade ?

Comment: Not a particularly useful piece of advice, but using `gsub` on a generated SQL query really scares me. I'm not familiar enough with Arel to really be helpful though, sorry

Comment: You are correct that the True Visitor was removed, which will impact `audios_published`  but you should be able to replace this with `Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(true)`. That being said this composition could use a complete overhaul.